# After overriding contoller how to best update handles

Tags: magento

Once i override controller:

```
            <!--...-->               
              <rewrite>          
                   <sj_storepickup_checkout_onepage>                      
                       <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/onepage/#]]></from>   
                            <to>/storepickup/checkout_onepage/</to>          
                   </sj_storepickup_checkout_onepage>                
              </rewrite>          
           <!--...-->
```

I am forced(because i don't know other way) to include layout file:

```
                 <!--...->
                     <layout>     
                         <updates>     
                             <storepickup>         
                                 <file>storepickup.xml</file>     
                              </storepickup>          
                         </updates>       
                     </layout>      
                <--...-->
```

so that i can update the new module(this case storepickup) handles to use orginal checkout_onepage_action handles that would be done as following in storepickup.xml

```
          <sj_storepickup_checkout_onepage_index>        
                <update handle="checkout_onepage_index"/>   
          </sj_storepickup_checkout_onepage_index>       

          <sj_storepickup_checkout_onepage_progress>        
              <update handle="checkout_onepage_progress"/>           
          </sj_storepickup_checkout_onepage_progress>

                               .
                               .
                               .
```

Otherwise the layout will render empty content block.

In the layout file storepickup.xml i am saying to use the original checkout layout handles and this seems a lot of repetitiveness and inefficient way to do it? Is there better way to update the handles? can i do the same thing within controller that way avoiding extra layout file to write/process?

Thank you,

Margots

Answer (score 4):

Overriding controllers directly was always a bit of hack, with a lot of undesired side effects.  Try using [the technique discussed here](http://web-magician.blogspot.com/2009/04/secret-feature-of-magento-13-sharing.html) to have Magento check your module first for a particular controller file.

```
<admin>
 <routers>
   <adminhtml>
     <args>
       <modules>
         <sintax before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mage_Sintax</sintax>
       </modules>
     </args>
   </adminhtml>
 </routers>
</admin>
```

It should leave your handle names intact.

Comment: +1, for such an informative basic answer, supporting Magento syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alan,...I did tried this before posting just to learn that Magento version 1.2 does not support this solution and the site is in version 1.2.  I believe this solution will only work for magento version 1.3 and above. please, correct me if i am wrong?

Any other ideas how to solve this in magento version 1.2 and below?